# Chrome Application is not closing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a close button for my chrome application and I've added the event listener to it. But now I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.contentWindow.close is not a function
```

Coming from line `227` in the Chrome library itself

```
AppWindow.prototype.moveTo = $Function.bind(window.moveTo, window);
AppWindow.prototype.resizeTo = $Function.bind(window.resizeTo, window);
AppWindow.prototype.contentWindow = window;
AppWindow.prototype.onClosed = new Event();
AppWindow.prototype.onWindowFirstShownForTests = new Event();
AppWindow.prototype.close = function() {
  this.contentWindow.close();
};
```

So I have multiple ways I've tried this first is as so

```
_.get = chrome.app.window.get.call(chrome,"main");
//second way
_.get = chrome.app.window.get("main");
//third way in dev panel
chrome.app.window.get("main").close();
//fourth way in dev panel
chrome.app.window.current().close();
```

Either way none of these will work because I think that there is something conflicting with the library itself. **THOUGH** everything works except for the close function.

Any suggestions as to why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking further into my code I realized I made a very big hiccup like an amatuer and clogged the global scope. I initialized a variable `close` which in turn made `window.close` equal my new variable :0